# Track usernames with piwik

Tags: customization, variables, statistics

I'm wondering if there is a way to send current logged username to Piwik and display it beside the ip address in the stats.

I need to see which users viewed a specific page and which users downloaded a specific file.

Is it possible to accomplish with custom variables?